# The difference b/w measure names and measure values

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have googled the difference but it has me confused. Measure names are the discrete or categorical fields, while measure values being the continuous ones. My question is :
In the screen grab, I have used the Sample- Superstore dataset that comes pre-downloaded with tableau desktop. I dragged Region in the columns tab and Sub category in the rows tab. Dragged Profit and Sales inside the table to get the following table. On the left side, under the Filters tab, why is it written Measure names when clearly Profit and Sales are measure values? Also, I see the same Measure names under the columns tab too. But aren't Profit and Sales measure values ??

Am I missing something in my understanding? Please helpppp [this is the screen grab of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23iEC.jpg)

Tried googling it. Got more confused

Answer (score 0):

Measure Names and Measure Values are placeholders in the Tableau user interface. (There are (obviously) no fields in your data source called "Measure Names" or "Measure Values".)

Instead, you can use Measure Values to tell Tableau to act on a set of measure fields in the same way. A typical use case is to put Measure Values on the Rows shelf with some other field, such as date field, on the Columns shelf. This tells Tableau to plot multiple measures using the same Y axis.

When you place the Measure Values pill on some shelf, such as Rows above, then Tableau displays a new shelf called Measure Values. You can then place multiple measure fields on that shelf. Tableau will treat all the Measures on the Measure Value shelf as if they were placed together as a block wherever the Measure Values pill is placed.

The Measure Names pill automatically is populated to list the names of the Measures on the Measure Values shelf.

In the example described above, a typical use would be to put Measure Names on Color or Label.

This feature seems a little confusing at first, but makes Tableau flexible. Its very useful for making tables and time series of multiple metrics. There are shortcuts that assist using Measure Values - one I use a lot is to drag a second measure directly onto an axis.